# Apache+WSGI+Python+Django giving me some strange errors

Tags: linux, debian, apache-http-server, python, mod-wsgi

Here's a summary of what I've done

- I moved my django project to `/pymodules/honstreams`
- I've installed apache2 and apache2-dev
- I've installed pythonbrew, installed Python-2.7.2 and switched to it
- I've set PYTHONPATH to `/pymodules` in `/etc/profile` and confirmed that it works
- I've compiled mod-wsgi.so using the correct python and apache versions
- I've added the wsgi module to httpd.conf
- I've created a wsgi_handler.py instructed by [this tutorial](http://www.technobabble.dk/2008/aug/25/django-mod-wsgi-perfect-match/). This is it:

  ```
  import sys
  import os

  sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/..')
  os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'honstreams.settings'

  import django.core.handlers.wsgi

  application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
  ```
- I've configured apache VirtualHost instructed by the same tutorial. I edited `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` to this:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *>

          ServerName www.honstreams.com
          ServerAlias *honstreams.com

          Alias /admin_media /root/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/ad$

          <Location /admin_media>
                  Order allow,deny
                  Allow from all
          </Location>

          Alias /media /root/honstreams/website/media

          <Location /media>
                  Order allow,deny
                  Allow from all
          </Location>

          WSGIScriptAlias / /root/honstreams/wsgi_handler.py

          WSGIDaemonProcess honstreams user=www-data group=www-data processes=1 threads=10
          WSGIProcessGroup honstreams

  </VirtualHost>
  ```

I start apache without errors. I try to access the root folder from http, and `/var/log/apache2/error.log` repeats:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
```

To be perfectly honest I haven't got a clue what to do next. I don't know what `<prefix>` or `<exec_prefix>` is and Google isn't being particularly helpful. I'm guessing I need to set the PYTHONHOME variable for user www-data.

Also I'm not trying to import a module named "site" in any of my code, anywhere, ever. Therefore I assume it'll fix itself if I fix the above errors.

Any help would be appreciated!

---

EDIT: I've set PYTHONHOME to `/root/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-2.7.2` in `/etc/profile`. I'm getting the exact same error as before. Does `/etc/profile` even have any effect when a user isn't being logged in at a shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew all along that my permissions were correct in my Python installation. What I did not know is that if a folder higher up in the hierarchy had more restricting permissions, that would make an impact.

The solution was to ensure that the entire chain of directories from root down to my python installation had rx permissions.

Answer (score 0):

As a first shot, I would follow Graham's advice here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946413/interesting-problem-with-python-2-7-on-centos-is-this-an-issue-with-my-build/6948092#6948092.  since you are using pythonbrew, to build with options use --configure="--enable-shared --whatever-other-options-you-need-go-here".  you may or may not need to symlink around your libraries a bit and explicitly add an LD_LIBRARY_PATH to your .bashrc. hth!